# Django | ¿Cómo se hace para que en una clase vista de tipo ListView se pueda llevar un context?

Tags: django

La intención es llevar un context al template cuando utilizamos un ListView. Normalmenta utilizo un return con el que llevo una consulta, pero al querer llevar más de una consulta me devuelve error. Parece que el context de esta manera devuelve error. En otro tipo de View lo he utilizado sin problema. Copn get_context_data he probado pero tampoco lo consigo. ¿Qué sucede?

**Error:**

El template muestra una estructura desajustada sin los datos que object_list debería mostrar. Y no se muestra el contenido de context.

**views.py**

```
class testFilterByModalityAndByUserView(ListView):
    model = TestQuestion
    template_name = 'test/question.html'
    urlReturn = 'test_app:test'
   
    def get_queryset(self):
        
        object_list = TestQuestion.objects.all()
        respuestas = UserAnswers.objects.all()
        context = {
            'respuestas': respuestas,
            }
        return object_list, context
        
    login_url = reverse_lazy('test_app:test')
```

Comment: Hola. ¿Qué error te da? Me huele a un `object does not support item assignment` por el `context['respuestas']` pero edita la pregunta y añade el error para tener más info.

Comment: Gracias Adrián. He puesto el código tal cual tengo. Más que error, me sucede que sin context todo va bien, pero en el momento que añado context, es como que el contenido de object_list deja de mostrarse. No se muestra ninguna información ni de una consulta, ni de la otra. Lo único que quiero es poder llevar más de una consulta al template, pero parece que se me resiste. ¿Qué sucede?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La manera correcta de modificar el context en un listview es sobreescribiendo el metodo get_context_data()

```
class testFilterByModalityAndByUserView(ListView):
    model = TestQuestion
    template_name = 'test/question.html'
    urlReturn = 'test_app:test'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(testFilterByModalityAndByUserView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['respuestas'] = UserAnswers.objects.all()
        return context
```

Si requieres agregar algo mas al contexto, solo necesitas definir la llave y el valor, por ejemplo:

```
context['preguntas'] = TestQuestion.objects.all()
```

Y con esto en tu template ya tienes {{preguntas}}

Espero te sea de ayuda.

Comment: Funciona perfecto. Muchas gracias Kevin!